# Android Studio / Intellij new project wizard

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have installed the new Android Studio. I would like to use it as my only IDE for my java and android apps.

I can import projects and then compile and work with them. But I cant create a new Java project.

Of course this was only released yet and it is "Android" Studio but as it is based on Intellij maybe it is possible to reactivate the selection for new project for Java and other. Right now if I click on new project I directly get the new Android project wizard.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this is not possible. If you want to work with pure Java, use IntelliJ. Android Studio is built for.. well, Android only!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can install the community version of IntelliJ and then install the Android plugins similar to Eclipse but I have not done this myself.