# Adding custom project wizard to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Android Studio to add a new type of project to the selection of project wizards. Unfortunately it seems like Android Studio blocks every project wizard besides the one for Android projects. So far I already have a solution which works well in IntelliJ but not in AS. I already took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575571/android-studio-intellij-new-project-wizard) but as I am trying to create a new wizard instead of reactivating an existing one I hope there might be a solution for that.

For everyone trying to convince me to use IntelliJ IDEA with Android Plugin instead: unfortunately this is **not** and option as I have to stick to Android Studio.

**tl;dr:** trying to create a project wizard in Android Studio. Works in Intellij IDEA but not in Android Studio.

Comment: Hi Niklas, did you get solution for it? I am stuck into same problem.

Comment: No, sorry. I gave up on it. If you find something it would be nice if you could give me a comment

Comment: I have got something, which I will explain you or share some links. But this is not about plugins, its about template.

Comment: I'm also trying to create a custom wizard